# cTAKES UMLS ICD10 codes lookup

Tags: ctakes

I created a cTAKES custom dictionary from UMLS database with ICD10 codes.

Right now I able to analyze the text by for example disease name, like `Asthma` and annotation index will contain the ICD10 code for this matching `code = "J45.90"`.

Is it possible to configure cTAKES in order to reverse this process in order to look for ICD10 code appearance in the text instead?

Answer (score 1):

The XML output contains the `start` and `end`s of a matched concept in the original corpus. I personally find it easier to convert the XML to a simple JSON format and then loop through it as needed.

I have been working on an open source solution for parsing out the data and displaying the corpus with the matches it in HTML: https://github.com/GoTeamEpsilon/ctakes-friendly-web-ui#demonstration - let me know if you'd like to contribute.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Right now in a scope of my R&D work I analyze the possibility to use cTAKES in our system. I need to analyze unstructured clinical notes in order for example to extract ICD10, CPT, HCPCS codes. Following your instructions on YouTube I have created custom cTAKES dictionary from UMLS database. Currently, I'm not very satisfied with the results because looks like cTAKES only use full string matching but I need fuzzy matching in order to extract the codes. Does cTAKES support this type of search?

Comment: Also, I tried to start up  with your ctakes-rest-service but ran into the following issue 
 https://github.com/GoTeamEpsilon/ctakes-rest-service/issues/28 Could you please also help on this?

Comment: @alexanoid Hi Alexanoid, you should have a look at the latest ctakes rest module in the following link - https://github.com/GoTeamEpsilon/ctakes-rest-service/tree/master/ctakes-web-rest This should be fairly straight forward to set up.